# maven2 using project.version and regex

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I want to use project version value from pom.xml in my jsp. I managed to do this by using filters, for exemple

```
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>login.jsp</include>
          </includes>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
```

And in my login.jsp i have
${version}

But the problem is that I need to substring my version number till the 2nd point: for example if the version is 5.0.3 in my jsp I want to show only 5.0.

How to do this? By using properties + regex or something else? I can always make it work by using js in the jsp page, but I would like to find another solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little old now, but I thought I might post my solution anyway for anyone else searching for a solution to this problem.

My solution makes use of the [Build Helper Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/).

This plugin makes it simple to parse and filter the version into a resource bundle/property file.

The first step is to add the plugin to your `pom` using something like the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <id>parse-version</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>parse-version</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then, in a property file in your `src/main/resources` directory, add the following property:

```
prettyBuildVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}
```

This will use just the first two numbers of the version.

To expose this property to your `JSP` so that it may be accessed using `EL`, make sure to add it to your `ServletContext` on startup.  Properties in the servlet context are directly accessible in JSPs using EL.

You could then include this property in any JSP in your application using `${prettyBuildVersion}`.